# getting error - Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-audio

I want to play audio as an alert but I'm getting an error like "Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first.

HTML Code:

```
<audio id="alarm" src="alarm.mp3"></audio>
```

JavaScript Code:

```
function alarm() {
    var value = document.getElementById("rvoltage").innerHTML;
    if (value > 230) {
        document.getElementById('alarm').play();
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64929753/play-failed-because-the-user-didnt-interact-with-the-document-first-issue)

Answer (score 5):

That is due to the fact that many browsers do not allow HTML elements to autoplay music and videos on page-load to save bandwidth etc. You could create a button and play the music on a click event or hack your way around it to make it play on *any* click event on your page.

> Autoplay with sound is allowed if:
>   User has interacted with the domain (click, tap, etc.).
>   On desktop, the user's Media Engagement Index threshold has been crossed, meaning the user has previously play video with sound.
>   On mobile, the user has [added the site to their home screen].

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes

Comment: @TamaghnaBanerjee I don't see how? This is in the question: "Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first", included in my answer: Autoplay with sound is allowed if: User has interacted with the domain (click, tap, etc.) among others. The reason for which the error occurs is clear: you cannot instantly play music unless the requirements have been met. (in chrome at least)

Comment: I got the answer. Thank you.