# User has to interact with Document error Chrome gives error when try to play music

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I know there are many questions about this theme but I have to ask because the solutions does not work in my case. I want to play a music. But Chrome says the user has to interact with the Document first.

````
var backMusic=new Audio("sounds/index.mp3");
          backMusic.loop=true;
          backMusic.volume=0.7;
          backMusic.play();```
````

Comment: Does this answer your question? [getting error - Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52963608/getting-error-uncaught-in-promise-domexception-play-failed-because-the-us)

Comment: @SebastianVittersø no unfortunately not. I have seen this sollution but I do not have an Audio Tag in my HTML. I create the Audio in Javascript.

Comment: I've not used the Audio-API too much, but if Chrome wants the user to first interact with the document, then it would be a bit of bad practice to work hard to get around it. I'd recommend setting up a few event listeners (onclick, onmousemove etc.) on the document, so that whenever the user HAS interacted with the Document, you can start the music.