# `.play()` failed because the user didn't interact with the document first issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-audio

I want to play sound, after my page has loaded.

Here is my JavaScript code:

```js
var playAudio = $("#sound")[0];
playAudio.play();
```

Here is my HTML code:

```html
<audio id="sound">
  <source src="../music/hide.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="../music/hide.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
</audio>
```

Console output:

`Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first.`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most browsers block any audio that is played by a web page and is not related to user interaction (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Media/Autoplay_guide). With user interaction I mean things like pressing a button. You can't do anything against that.

But you could add a start button that displays the page and starts the music, like this:

```js
const startbtn = document.getElementById("startbtn");
const content = document.getElementById("content");
const loader = document.getElementById("loader");
const music = document.getElementById("music");

//Add an event listner to the start button
startbtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  //Show the loader and hide the button
  loader.style.display = "";
  startbtn.style.display = "none";
  //Wait for the music to start
  music.play().then(() => {
    //Hide the loader and show the content
    content.style.display = "";
    loader.style.display = "none";
  });
});
```

```html
<!-- The start button --->
<button id="startbtn">Start</button>

<!-- The actual content, hidden by default -->
<div id="content" style="display: none;">
  <p>Bla</p>
  <p>Bla</p>
  <p>Bla</p>
  <p>Bla</p>
  <p>Bla</p>
  <p>Bla</p>
  <p>Bla</p>
  <p>Bla</p>
  <p>Bla</p>
  <p>Bla</p>
  <p>Bla</p>
  <p>Bla</p>
  <p>Bla</p>
  <p>Bla</p>
  <p>Bla</p>
  <p>Bla</p>
  <p>Bla</p>
  <p>Bla</p>
  <p>Bla</p>
  <p>Bla</p>
  <p>Bla</p>
  <p>Bla</p>
</div>

<!-- This is displayed when the user has pressed the start button, but the music is still loading -->
<div id="loader" style="display: none;">
  <p>Loading ...</p>
</div>

<!-- The music. It is started by the Javascript -->
<audio id="music" src="https://opengameart.org/sites/default/files/audio_preview/swing_0.mp3.ogg" style="display: none;" loop></audio>
```

Comment: i want to do thing like when i entering a web site music is playing but if user want to stop so he just press a button.Can i do this?and how?

Comment: No, the browser will block the audio automatically. But you could display only a start button when the website is loaded and show the whole page and play the music when the start button was pressed. But I don't know if that fits your scenario.

Comment: how can i make button before web site loaded?

Comment: what if the button clicked by jquery... is that make sense of playing it automatically?

Comment: Is there any way "autoplay"?

Answer (score 1):

When this happens on **Google Chrome**, the error is currently showing a link to this page: https://developer.chrome.com/blog/autoplay/.

As the post explains, Google Chrome keeps track of an **individual's propensity to consume media on a site**, using a metric called **MEI (Media Engagement Index)**.

Based on that metric, an attempt to play sound on page load may or may not work. You can see a list of the scores of which Chrome keeps track by going to `chrome://media-engagement/` on your browser.

To handle cases in which the play on page load doesn't work, the post suggests the following code snippet:

```js
var promise = document.querySelector('video').play();

if (promise !== undefined) {
  promise.then(_ => {
    // Autoplay started!
  }).catch(error => {
    // Autoplay was prevented.
    // Show a "Play" button so that user can start playback.
  });
}
```

In your case it could be:

```
const playAudio = $("#sound")[0];
const promise = playAudio.play();

let playedOnLoad;

if (promise !== undefined) {
  promise.then(_ => {
    // Autoplay started!
    playedOnLoad = true;
  }).catch(error => {
    // Autoplay was prevented.
    playedOnLoad = true;
  });
}
```

At this point you can use the `playedOnLoad` value to show a **button** or **add a listener** to some other types of user interaction.

Another option (the one I'm adopting) is to always **show a toggle** for the sound, and to change it's state (play/stop or enable/disable) based on the **result of the promise**.

Please remember that the **MEI score** is also saved for your **local development** environment, so, based on your personal interaction with the page, the sound may or may not start on page load **even in your local environment**.