# Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first

Tags: javascript

```
var buttonColours = ["red", "blue", "green", "yellow"];

var gamePattern = [];

function nextSequence() {

  var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
  var randomChosenColour = buttonColours[randomNumber];
  gamePattern.push(randomChosenColour);

  $("#" + randomChosenColour).fadeIn(100).fadeOut(100).fadeIn(100);

  var audio = new Audio("sounds/" + randomChosenColour + ".mp3");
  audio.play();
}

nextSequence();
```

The play() function is not working and it is giving the error
"Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first."

Suggest some fix.

Comment: Are you calling `nextSequence()` after the document is ready?

Comment: I was just checking if the function works. But it was showing this error in console.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64929753/play-failed-because-the-user-didnt-interact-with-the-document-first-issue)

Answer (score 2):

This a feature in most of modern browsers to prevent malicious/spam actions by website developers. So basically the web pages will not be able to auto-play videos/audios except when the user interacts with the website first (clicks, hovers, points, etc.).

So in your case, `nextSequence()` should be called when the user clicks on something for example.

```
document.getElementById("playbutton").addEventListener("click", nextSequence);
```

Comment: That was to check if the function was working or not. $("#" + randomChosenColour).fadeIn(100).fadeOut(100).fadeIn(100); -- this part is working but not the "audio.play()". It is showing the error this error in console - "Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first."