# DOMException: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first (audio call ring)

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I want to customize the talk app in nextcloud to ring the othe user when start video call like messenger so I added this bit of code on this event of starting call

```
        const audio = new Audio(require('../../alo.mp3'))
        audio.autoplay = true
        audio.setAttribute('type', 'application/x-mpegURL')
        audio.play()
```

but it gives me in the console this error

> DOMException:play()failed because the user didn't interact with the document first

I need this audio to autoplay like messenger

Comment: Is this a web application?  If so were you using Chrome by chance?  If you are, Chrome has updated their playback policies.  By default Chrome does not play audio unless the dom is interacted with first.

Comment: I read this but how facebook messenger work ?? its call make ring and this is my case

Comment: Does this answer your question? [play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64929753/play-failed-because-the-user-didnt-interact-with-the-document-first-issue)