# How can play notification sound when arrived a notification in reactJs (I got error DOMException: play() failed)

Tags: reactjs, audio, notifications

I created a pwa app in react and websocket.
I want when recieve notificaion play a sound but I got this error:

`Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first`

How can I fix this error?

I create a button and click on it programically but still get this

Comment: This is an audio API issue. Some browsers need a user gesture, before playing any sound at all. A user gesture meaning: a user event, e.g. click performed by a user. Afaik there is currently not a way to consistently playback audio without one (in most browsers). See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64929753/play-failed-because-the-user-didnt-interact-with-the-document-first-issue

Comment: That means that, you have to wait until the user clicks anything on the website before you can use `.play()`