# Is there a way to autoplay audio in html?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to autoplay audio in my website as soon as I open my site. But it doesn't work.

```
  <audio id="myAudio" autoplay>
  <source src="./Welcome to Kitchen Nightmares..mp3" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="./Welcome to Kitchen Nightmares..mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  </audio>
  <script>
    function myFunction() {
      var x = document.getElementById("myAudio").autoplay;
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
    }
    myFunction();
```

Comment: browser like mozilla block autoplay until user give permission.

Comment: the autoplay attribute on the audio tag was enough. With valid sources it's working on my firefox with no permissions given.

Comment: for further analysis, this is the mdn page about that https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Media/Autoplay_guide

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
function PlayMusic() {

  var play=document.getElementById("music");
  play.play();
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  setTimeout(PlayMusic,3000);
})

</script>
</head>
<body>

<audio controls id="music" >

  <source src="https://www.computerhope.com/jargon/m/example.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>

</body>
</html>
```

After page load audio will play (1 sec delay).

> URL   The URL of the audio file. Possible values:
>
> An absolute URL - points to another web site (like
> src="http://www.example.com/horse.ogg")
>
> A relative URL - points to a
> file within a web site (like src="horse.ogg")

Comment: error : failed because the user didn't interact with the document first.

Comment: most of browser block audio playing i think you can prefer this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64929753/play-failed-because-the-user-didnt-interact-with-the-document-first-issue

Comment: if still requires help let me share your code snip

Answer (score -1):

Should start playing the audio file when the page loads, thanks to the `autoplay` attribute on the `<audio>` element. The buttons in the HTML code allow you to control the audio playback by calling the `play()` and `pause()` methods on the `<audio>` element.

Note that some browsers may not allow audio to automatically play on a website due to user experience and security concerns. In these cases, the user may need to explicitly start the audio playback by clicking on a button or some other element on the page.

```
<audio id="myAudio" autoplay>
  <source src="./Welcome to Kitchen Nightmares..mp3" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="./Welcome to Kitchen Nightmares..mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>

<p>
  <button onclick="playAudio()">Play Audio</button>
  <button onclick="pauseAudio()">Pause Audio</button>
</p>

<script>
  function playAudio() {
    var audio = document.getElementById("myAudio");
    audio.play();
  }

  function pauseAudio() {
    var audio = document.getElementById("myAudio");
    audio.pause();
  }
</script>
```

Comment: It's not "autoplay"