# How is youtube able to autoplay video without it being muted in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, html5-video

Auto playing video in the HTML5 gives an exception:

`DOMException: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first.`

There is a workaround by muting the video first.

I'm wondering how is youtube able to get around this restriction and not have to mute their videos (if you navigate to a youtube video URL directly in incognito, it plays on it's own).

Note: muting and unmuting the video doesn't work

Comment: Autoplay with sound is not allowed in modern browsers due to the `Autoplay Policy`. YouTube can autoplay because it is whitelisted, this whitelist can also vary depending how often you visit some websites.

Comment: @ControlAltDel - the video is in a `<video>` tag

Comment: I've explained the situation in this answer. Although the question is not the same, I think my answer can be relevant here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77357456/2342537

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you described is a result of browser policies regarding automatic playback of videos with sound. To improve the user experience and prevent sudden and unwanted audio playback, many web browsers enforce restrictions on autoplaying videos with sound.
:D